# Push elements into array where a month is missing

Tags: php, arrays, default-value

I want to fill missing months in an array with zeros.

Input Data:

```
$d = [
        [
          'type' =>  25500,
          'month' => 'July'
         ],
         [
          'type' => 5465,
          'month' => 'January'
         ],
         [
          'type' => 40000,
          'month' => 'April'
         ],
         [
          'type' => 35000,
          'month' => 'June'
         ],
         [
          'type' => 10000,
          'month' => 'February'
     ]
 ];

$allmonths = ['January','February','March', 'April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
```

My Code:

```
$res = [];
foreach ($allmonths  as $key => $mes) {
    $teste = array_search($mes, array_column($d, 'month'));
    if ($teste) {
        $res[$teste] = ['type' => 2, 'moth '=> $mes];
    } else {
        $res[] = ['type' => 0,'moth '=> $mes];
    }
}
```

I have been trying to solve this problem but with no success.

Expected Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => 25500
            [month] => July
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => 5465
            [month] => January
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => 40000
            [month] => April
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => 35000
            [month] => June
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => 10000
            [month] => February
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [type] => 0
            [month] => March
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [type] => 0
            [month] => May
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [type] => 0
            [month] => August
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [type] => 0
            [month] => September
        )
    [9] => Array
        (
            [type] => 0
            [month] => October
        )
    [10] => Array
        (
            [type] => 0
            [month] => November
        )
    [11] => Array
        (
            [type] => 0
            [month] => December
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will go with [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and a single `foreach()`

Process:

1)Create an array of all months

2)Get all month present in your array using `array_column()`.

3)Find the not available months in your array using `array_diff()`.

4)Iterate over this difference and add them to your current array.

```
$allMonths = ['January','February','March', 'April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

$currentMonths = array_column($d, 'month');

$notIncludedMonth = array_diff($allMonths,$currentMonths);

foreach ($notIncludedMonth as $month) {
    $d[] = [
        'type' => 0,
        'month' => $month,
    ];
}

print_r($d);
```

Output : https://3v4l.org/GsFoO

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work:

```php
<?php

$d = [
       [
         'type' =>  25500,
         'month' => 'July'
        ],
        [
         'type' => 5465,
         'month' => 'January'
        ],
        [
         'type' => 40000,
         'month' => 'April'
        ],
        [
         'type' => 35000,
         'month' => 'June'
        ],
        [
         'type' => 10000,
         'month' => 'February'
        ]
      ];

$allmonths = ['January','February','March', 'April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

$present_months = array_column($d, 'month');

foreach ($allmonths as $month) {
    if (!in_array($month, $present_months)) {
        $d[] = [
            'type' => 0,
            'month' => $month,
        ];
    }
}

var_dump($d);
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers on Stack Overflow.  Always endeavor to educate/empower the asker and thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

Since the objective here is to append missing months to the original array `$d` without changing the existing `elements` (as per the expected result), we can simply change `$d` instead of creating a new variable `$res`.

Also converting the keys of the array `$d` will make it much easier to work with. This does assume that `month` appears only once in `$d`.

[Link to working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0310b0cf8756c962be3c7851d041fcc4ffdc1bbf)

```php
## Assumption: Month is unique
$dNew = array_column($d, null, 'month');
$res = [];
foreach ($allmonths as $key => $mes) {
    if (!isset($dNew[$mes])) {
        $d[] = ['type' => 0, 'moth ' => $mes];
    }
}
var_dump($d);
```

If `month` is not unique in the array you can use `array_search` or `in_array` to get similar results.

```
$dNew = array_column($d,  'month');
$res = [];
foreach ($allmonths as $key => $mes) {
    if (!array_search($mes, $dNew)) {
        $d[] = ['type' => 0, 'moth ' => $mes];
    }
}
print_r($d);
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer goes to the extra effort of putting the months in order (not that you requested it -- it just feels right to me).

Also, efficiency is probably not a focal point for this task, but for researchers' benefit I'll express that `in_array()`, `array_search()`, `array_diff()`, and any other "value comparing" technique are not able to work as efficiently as "key comparing" techniques such as `array_key_exists()`, `isset()`, `??` (null coalescing operator), `array_diff_key()`, etc.  For this reason, I favor endeavor's first snippet -- `!isset()` will perform very well within a loop.

Here is my alternative which makes no iterated function calls (but does iterate the full array of months). ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4dNfC))

```
$lookup = array_column($d, null, 'month');  // assign temporary keys for improved efficiency

$result = [];
foreach ($allmonths as $month) {
    $result[] = $lookup[$month] ?? ['type' => 0, 'month' => $month];
}
var_export($result);
```